# How to subscribe to openni topics inside a package

Tags: kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have ros-fuerte, ros-fuerte-openni-camera, ros-fuerte-openni-launch installed. I can launch openni from terminal and using rostopic echo /topic_name, I can get all data. The data is also visible on rviz.

Now, I need to use this data inside a program (for example in a cpp file) and I am unable to find out how. Here is what I did:

1. I created a package using roscreate-pkg, and tried putting some cpp files inside src and all compiled and run successfully after amending my CMakeLists.txt. I successfully subscribed to some turtlesim topics inside the cpp file.
2. Now I tried to subscribe to an openni topic (cpp file attached).
   My first question is: Why openni-camera is located at ros/stack/openni rather than ros/include/... just like other packages (opencv and pcl)? Does it make any difference where actually openni is installed?
3. Because openni is installed at ros/stacks/ I have to manually give path to include its .h files (see #include in cpp file). Is it right approach?
4. The cpp file just does not compile with the error (fatal error: XnCppWrapper.h: No such file or directory). I tried to search my computer and couldnt find XnCppWrapper.h. Where is that file located and why my program cant find it?
5. Do I need to set a path for ros to use openni while compiling a cpp file inside a package

I am pretty confused and have spent a lot of time on it without any success. Any help to clarify will be appreciated a lot.

#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include </opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/include/openni_camera/openni_depth_image.h>

void OpenniCallback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr& msg)
{
ROS_INFO("I heard")//: [%f]", msg->linear, msg->angular);
//ROS_INFO("I heard");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

ros::init(argc, argv, "openni_subscriber");
ros::NodeHandle n;

ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/camera/depth/points", 1000, OpenniCallback);
ros::spin();

return 0;
}

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122771/how-to-subscribe-to-openni-topics-inside-a-package/) by [Latif Anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/4454/latif-anjum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2014-01-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Latif Anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/4454/latif-anjum/) on 2014-01-27**:
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include </opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/include/openni_camera/openni_depth_image.h>

void OpenniCallback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2::ConstPtr& msg)
{
ROS_INFO("I heard")//: [%f]", msg->linear, msg->angular);
//ROS_INFO("I heard");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

ros::init(argc, argv, "openni_subscriber");
ros::NodeHandle n;

ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/camera/depth/points", 1000, OpenniCallback);
ros::spin();

return 0;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It doesn't really matter where `openni` is installed. As long as your manifest, CMakeLists, and ROS environment variables are correct, you shouldn't have a problem.  Also, you should not be having to include paths to get things to compile.

What you are trying to do doesn't really have much to do with the `openni` package.  The `openni` package will connect to your depth camera and produce the topic */camera/depth/points*.  It seems that you are trying to subscribe to that topic.  So your package should depend on packages like `sensor_msgs`, `pcl`, and maybe `pcl_ros`.

Here is a `manifest.xml`

```
<package>
  <depend package="roscpp"/>    
  <depend package="sensor_msgs"/>
</package>
```

Here is a `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE Release)

rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

rosbuild_add_executable(openni_subscriber src/openni_subscriber.cpp)
```

Here is a slightly modified version of your code that compiles and works correctly:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>

void OpenniCallback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr &msg)
{
    ROS_INFO("I heard");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "openni_subscriber");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/camera/depth/points", 1, OpenniCallback);
    ros::spin();
    return 0;
}
```

Check out [this page](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Overview) to see examples of how to subscribe to Point Cloud messages, and [this page](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Tutorials) for more complete examples on using `PCL` with ROS.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2014-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Latif Anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/4454/latif-anjum/) on 2014-01-27**:
Thank you sir. You did solve the problem. Looking forward to your guidance in future as well.

**Comment by [Latif Anjum](https://answers.ros.org/users/4454/latif-anjum/) on 2014-01-27**:
The statement #include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h> gives an error. It says no such file. This file is actually located in my case at pcl-1.5/pcl/point_cloud.h. I gave this path but there are now other errors. Same is the case with #include <pcl/point_types.h>. Any guidance?